# Add/Remove Highlights to the Words in MS Office Word document OfficeJS

Tags: jquery, ms-word, office-js

I need to highlight words in Word document in my Add-in and when the user needs to remove highlight made by Add-in, it should be possible to remove only the highlights that are made by the Add-in.
User made highlights should not be removed.

Right now I can highlight the words with red color in my Add-in and when the user wants to remove highlights, even the user highlights also removed.

Below is my code:

```
//Add highlights
return context.sync().then(function () {
// Queue a set of commands to change the font for each found item.
for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
    searchResults.items[i].font.color = 'red';
    searchResults.items[i].font.underline = 'wave';
}
return context.sync();
});

//Remove highlights
Word.run(function (context) {
            // Create a proxy object for the document body.
            var body = context.document.body;

            // Queue a commmand to clear the contents of the body.
            body.load("font");

            return context.sync().then(function () {
                // Queue a set of commands to change the font for each found item.
                body.font.color = 'black';
                body.font.underline = 'None';
                return context.sync();
            })
                .catch(errorHandler);
        });
```

Comment: If this were the COM API I'd recommend to *bookmark* the highlighted ranges. Bookmarks aren't (yet?) supported in the JS APIs so next best would be to put the ranges the code highlights into *ContentControl*s. Format the appearance of the content controls to "Hidden" so that they aren't "obvious" to the user. You'd also want to set them to "cannotDelete = true". So, when the code removes highlights it only does so for content in one of the content controls that were created when highlighting text. And removing the highlight would also remove the content control.

Comment: Could you just repeat the original search at the beginning of the remove highlights method, and unhighlight the results? *IF* the user has created new content that matches the search criteria and *if* the user manually highlighted it, then it would be unhighlighted too. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: As of now, even that's better @RickKirkham

Answer (score 2):

you have a couple of options for this.

1. You can store the ranges where you made the highlights.
2. You can wrap the range results with an invisible content control (as Cindy Suggests in her comment),
   create a tag and then traverse those content controls (using content controls get by tag method) to unformat
   your highlights (and remove the content controls.

2) is kind of straightforward to implement :)

For 1) please check out the following example, its not doing exactly what you need, but you can get an idea on how to achieve this. The goal is to save each range using the treackedObjects method, that the most important bit.  On this case I am creating an array of the ranges that where found, and then you can use it to clean up your highlights. please dont forget to call  context.trackedObjects.remove  since you are allocating memory to store those objects temporally.  By the way in my example make sure to include a combo itesm with id "FoundRanges"

here is a [script lab snippet](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/05dcde2ab360b1cb7dcec22f7a729a3a) you can use.

```js
function loadCombo() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var rangesAr = [];
        var currentlySelectedIndex = 0;
        var myRanges = context.document.body.search("Word");
        context.load(myRanges, { expand: 'font' });
        return context.sync()

            .then(function () {
                var myCombo = document.getElementById("FoundRanges");

                for (var i = 0; i < myRanges.items.length; i++) {
                    var myItem = document.createElement("option");
                    myItem.text = myRanges.items[i].text
                    myCombo.add(myItem);
                    var newRange = myRanges.items[i].getRange();
                    rangesAr.push(newRange);
                    context.trackedObjects.add(newRange);
                   
                }
                $('#FoundRanges').change(function () {
                    
                    rangesAr[this.selectedIndex].font.bold = true;
                    currentlySelectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
                    return context.sync()
                        .catch(function (e) {
                           console.og(e.message);
                        })
                });
                return context.sync()
            })
            
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    })
}
```